# Only return search results that matches in all fields

Tags: solr, lucene, requesthandler, dismax

I have fields for name and dimensions. The fields are: `Name`, `dimensionLength`, `dimensionWidth` and `dimensionHeight`.

I want query `productX 10x20` only to return matches containing both dimensions. So query above can return `productX 10x20x30` and `productX 10x30x20`, but shouldn't return `productX 10x30x40`.

The first results are fine, but i get many other irrelevant matches. Any Ideas how to avoid these irrelevant results?

To clarify, fields are:

```
 <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="Height_mm_Copy" stored="false" type="dimension"/>
 <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="Outside_diameter_mm_Copy" stored="false" type="dimension"/>
 <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="Inside_diameter_mm_Copy" stored="false" type="dimension"/>
 <field indexed="true" name="name" stored="true" type="title"/>
```

Fieldtype for dimensions:

```
 <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="dimension" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)+([.][0])" replacement="$1"/>
 <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/> 
 <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>

 <analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="," replace="all" replacement="."/>
 <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)+([.][0])" replacement="$1"/>
 <filter catenateAll="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateWords="0" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="1" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="1" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
 <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
```

requestHandler:

```
  <requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler" >
<lst name="defaults">
 <str name="defType">dismax</str>
 <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
 <float name="tie">0.3</float>

 <str name="qf">
    supplierArticleId_Prefix
 </str>     
 <str name="fl">
    UUID,score
 </str>
 <str name="mm">
    3&lt;-1 5&lt;-2 6&lt;90%
 </str>
 <int name="ps">100</int>
 <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
   <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by making a copy field of "name". By using 
`<filter class="solr.PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+/*[xX]\d+)" preserve_original="false"/>` in the fieldType for this field. So from string "product 10x20x30" only "10x20" remains indexed in this field.